# How should I interpret “...and what modern epistemologist would...”?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

The sentence goes as follow:

> ...and what modern epistemologist would greet an authoritative
> pronouncement that she in fact possessed knowledge by trying to refute
> it?

I have two different understandings of this sentence:

a) What **kind of** modern epistemologist **(i.e. among all kinds of modern epistemologists, who)** would greet an authoritative pronouncement that she in fact possessed knowledge by trying to refute it?

b) **How (i.e. in what way) will** modern epistemologist greet an authoritative pronouncement that she in fact possessed knowledge by trying to refute it?

Which one is correct? If neither, what does this sentence mean?

Furthermore, what does "greet" in this sentence mean? Does it mean "embrace", or "view"? And, what does "possess**ed** knowledge by trying to refute it" mean? Does the preposition "by" indicate **time** - as if, *modern epistemologists have **already** possessed knowledge **before** trying to refute it*, or **means** - as if, *modern epistemologists possess knowledge by means of trying to refute it*?

I noticed that a past tense of "possess" is used here. That somehow troubles me. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're over-thinking this one. It's a rhetorical question, structurally equivalent to *What sane person would deny Darwin's Theory of Evolution?* To which the expected / assumed answer is *There is no such "sane person"* (or *...no such "modern epistemologist"*). I assume it's supposed to be a clever "in-joke" - maybe the writer thinks no modern epistemologists believe that anyone knows anything, so they might naturally try to argue with anyone who suggested that ***they*** knew something. But it passes me by.  ***Greet*** here is just a quirky figurative way of saying ***responds to***.

Comment: Note that ***possessed*** there is "backshifted" as an optional stylistic choice. For example, *He said I **possessed** great charm* is often 100% equivalent to and interchangeable with *He said I **possess** great charm*. If the speaker is proud of having the reported attribute, perhaps he'd be more likely to use Present tense. But not necessarily.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica So I was totally misreading the whole sentence! Now it seems to me that "by" is referring to "greet" as if "greet the pronouncement by refuting it", rather than "possess", as if "possess knowledge by refuting it". Is that correct?

Comment: Btw thanks for the information on the backshifted verb. Is it backshifted because "would" is used here? Just saying, but, "would" seems not like an authentic past tense used here (cr. "He said I possess great charm"), it seems more of a subjunctive mood. Is it still possible to backshift it if this is the case?

Comment: I don't think the subjunctive is a useful concept here. In *People who know me **will/would** say I **have/had** great charm* only ***will+had*** is idiomatically unacceptable (the other 3 permutations are all fine). I personally don't much like ***knew*** for the first verb form there - but curiously, I find I'm fine with ***Anyone** who **knew** me **would** say [blah, blah]*. In principle your writer could have asked *what modern epistemologist **greets** [some pronouncement]*, in which case it would NOT be acceptable to use past tense ***possessed*** in the subordinate clause.